# Export data with OPCUa subscription in IoT Edge

Tags: python, async-await, opc-ua, azure-iot-edge

I am trying to receive data as an OPCUA client, therefore I created a subscription for some data nodes. Receiving data is no problem, but exporting it as an IoT Client is the problem. I think I have to run 2 threads paralel. The following code is used:

```
class Publisher():
    def __init__(self):
        self.module_client = IoTHubModuleClient.create_from_edge_environment()


    async def export_data(self, message, output):
        """Serializes databuffer to json string"""
        print('Export')
        self.module_client.send_message_to_output(message, output)
        print('Exported completed')


class Handler(object):
    """
    Client to subscription. It will receive events from server
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """"""
        self.publisher = Publisher()


    def datachange_notification(self, node, val, data):
        self.publisher.export_data('test', 'output1')


url = "opc.tcp://192.168.3.5:4840"
opcua_client = Client(url)
opcua_client.connect()
opcua_broker = Handler()

sub = opcua_client.create_subscription(20, opcua_broker)
node_list = [opcua_client.get_node('ns=3;s="EM126_Log"."DataLogL"[1]')]
handler = sub.subscribe_data_change(node_list)

time.sleep(100)
```

The error is as follows:
"RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Publisher.export_data' was never awaited"

Does anyone know how to export the incoming data in de Handler class (datachange_notfication)

Comment: `async def export_data` you defined here a coroutine. That needs to be `await`ed. Coroutines are used in asynchronous code so they can be run in parallel. Provide a minimal example. Your import statements are missing. Also do a `pip freeze` and provide information which opcua library you are using. You should refrain from using `time.sleep()` in asynchronous code. It halts your entire program. If the opcua library supports asyncio then you won't need parallel threads.

Comment: Hi Tin, these imports are used:
from azure.iot.device.aio import IoTHubModuleClient
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
from opcua import Client
import asyncio
import time

Comment: I also tried to add the export in the datachange_notification, but that does not work. That was the reason that I tried to use 2 seperate threads.